# How to reload data for line chart in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, charts

I am using Charts library for rendering line chart but I am unable to reload the data as I am trying to fetch the data from the API, there is a method given notifyDataSetChanged() but not working. I am using the chart within tableView cell. If anybody has some idea please help me out..............................................

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class ChartViewCell: UITableViewCell, ChartViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var lineChartViewContainer: UIStackView?

    var yVlaues = [ChartDataEntry]()
    
    lazy var lineChartView: LineChartView = {
        let chartView = LineChartView()
        
        return chartView
    }()
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setLineChart()
        loadData()
        
        
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
    }
    
    func setLineChart() {
        lineChartView.delegate = self
        lineChartView.noDataText = "No Data Found"
        lineChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
        lineChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        lineChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        lineChartView.legend.enabled = false
        //lineChartView.leftAxis.labelFont = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        lineChartView.leftAxis.labelCount = 6
        lineChartView.leftAxis.labelTextColor = .black
        lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        
        lineChartView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 70, width: screenWidth - 20, height: 200)
        setData()
        self.addSubview(lineChartView)
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
        print("Abhay x \(entry.x) y \(entry.y)")
    }
    

    
    
    func setData() {
        let set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: yVlaues)
        set1.lineWidth = 1
        set1.colors = [UIColor.colorFromHex(hexString: "#80005661")]
        set1.drawVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true
        set1.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = false
        set1.highlightColor = UIColor.colorFromHex(hexString: "#80005661")
        set1.highlightLineWidth = 1.0
        set1.drawValuesEnabled = false
        set1.circleHoleColor = .white
        set1.circleColors = [UIColor.colorFromHex(hexString: "#80005661")]
        set1.circleRadius = 5
        
        
        
        let data = LineChartData(dataSet: set1)
        lineChartView.data = data
        
        let startColor = UIColor.colorFromHex(hexString: "#80005661").cgColor
        let endColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        
        let gradientColors = [startColor, endColor] as CFArray // Colors of the gradient
        let colorLocations:[CGFloat] = [1.0, 0.0] // Positioning of the gradient
        let gradient = CGGradient.init(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: gradientColors, locations: colorLocations) // Gradient Object
        if let gradient = gradient {
            set1.fill = Fill.fillWithLinearGradient(gradient, angle: 90.0) // Set the Gradient
        }
        
        set1.drawFilledEnabled = true // Draw the Gradient
        
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        var params = [String: Any]()
        guard let userId = Reusable.getUserInfo()?.id else { return }
        params = ["user_id": userId]
        
        WebServiceHelper.postWebServiceCall(Constants.baseURL + "performedWorkoutsGraph", params: params, isShowLoader: false, success: { (responceObj) in
            
            let statusMsg = StatusBool(json: responceObj)
            if statusMsg.status {
                self.yVlaues.removeAll()
                let responseJsonArr = responceObj["data"].arrayValue
                for item in responseJsonArr {
                    let graphData = GraphDataModel(json: item)
                    let chartDataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(graphData.interval), y: Double(graphData.workouts))
                    self.yVlaues.append(chartDataEntry)
                }
                
                self.lineChartView.data?.notifyDataChanged()
                self.lineChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
            } else {
                CommonUtils.showToastMessage(message: statusMsg.message)
            }
        }
       , failure: { (failure) in
            print(failure)
       })
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution but not the reloading tricks I m calling setData() inside my loadData() and it's working